# Add a blind spot to 360 Lidar

Tags: lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am using the Neato Lidar which is 360.  However if part of it is blocked, it gets really confused.

Is there a way to tell ROS, don't use angle x to y on this sensor?

Should I just use a Kinect instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255568/add-a-blind-spot-to-360-lidar/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-25**:
See my answer to #q255110.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-25**:
Thanks again mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [#q255110](http://answers.ros.org/question/255110/), `LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter` allows you to change the range start and stop.

The [laser_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters) package also includes `LaserScanAngularBoundsFilterInPlace` to remove an arbitrary chuck, instead of changing the start and stop angles.

Example usage:
https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/mobility_base_ros/src/622c06daa4b73ae60ab899e5ecf9ca4aa4e3bbf8/mobility_base_bringup/launch/birdcage_laser_pipeline.launch
https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/mobility_base_ros/src/622c06daa4b73ae60ab899e5ecf9ca4aa4e3bbf8/mobility_base_bringup/yaml/birdcage_laser_filter_params.yaml

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0